# Is it possible to customize loading spinner of forge viewer version 7?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I see the loading spinner is changed in forge viewer version 7.28 (https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v7/#id6) and I cannot find any documentation on customizing this.

Is it possible to customize loading spinner in version 7.28 or later ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following this guide, you will find a way to customize the old loading spinner :
[Custom Viewer Loading Spinner](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-viewer-loading-spinner)

It's not working from 7.28 as the class name change to `forge-spinner`. But if you replace the name `spinner` with `forge-spinner`, you will be able to make it working!

Comment: thanks for the quick answer! I did see this post from searching and feel silly that I haven't tried changing the class name.